# About irreducible group representations

Tags: representation-theory

[image]Are the trivial representation, the alternating representation and the standard representation irreducible representations?!

I can easily see that the trivial representation (which sends every element in the group to the identity mapping), is reducible representation!

Comment: Ok I got it! these reps are on C, so they are one-dimensional reps, and they are irreducible :) 
Thanks!

Comment: The third representation defined here seems to make no sense for $n > 3$. I mean for example if $\sigma \in S_4$ switches $1$ and $4$ and fixes $2$ and $3$ the definition would suggest $\sigma (z_1,z_2,z_3) ) (z_4,z_2,z_3)$ but there is no $z_4$... The correct standard representation should be on $V = \{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n \:|\: \sum_{i} z_i = 0\}$ I believe.

Comment: The standard representation is irreducible. The irreducible representations of $S_{n}$ correspond to partitions of $n$ and the standard representation corresponds to the partition $(n-1, 1).$

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh thanks alot! 
could you please suggest me  a reference to study the representations of Sn, I feel I'm interested in them :)

Comment: The best reference is probably Fulton and Harris "Representation Theory: a first course". Alternatively, you have lecture notes by Pavel Etingof here: http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf. These are good notes for representation theory in general. Yufei Zhao has also written a pretty nice expository article on the representations of $S_{n}$ here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~margalit/repthy/Basic%20summary%20of%20young%20tableaux.pdf.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Thank you, i appreciate it! :)